# Arduino uno shift register

Tags: shift-register

I have shift register 74HC595. I added 7 push buttons from Q1-7 and the 8th to ground. On the other side which pin of the register will go to Arduino pin 2? And wich one to the 5v pin?

How can I read one button at a time in the code because on the Arduino it is just 1 pin?

Comment: *my problem is that i have a lot off buttons 16 how can i do it a 4x4 buttons* - do you have 7 buttons or 16 buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.  The 74HC595 does not have parallel inputs, such as you would need to read from 7 switches.

You need a parallel-in, serial-out shift register, such as a [CD4021B](http://www.ti.com/product/CD4021B).  You can find details on how to use it with an Arduino [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftIn)

> How can I read one button at a time in the code because on the Arduino it is just 1 pin?

Basically you "clock in" the data by toggling a clock line - each toggle presents the next bit, which you read in using your one digital input.

Comment: Okay , my problem is that i have a lot off buttons 16 how can i do it a 4x4 buttons with there values to send them to windows form

Comment: And does it work with just the arduino pins?

Comment: How many unused digital pins do you have on your Arduino?

Comment: I think i just need the grnd and the 5v , i dont have anything attached to the arduino just the buttons , my goal is to play a game i created with those buttons

Comment: If you post another question, asking how to connect 8 switches to an Arduino, I'll answer it - since it's a different question and this one has already been answered.

Comment: Just one. I have a 4x4 labels in C# on each button press i want to change its color

Comment: Okay I'll post a new question

Comment: OK. If you want to encourage people to help you further, then if your question has been answered (never mind that it wasn't the question that you should have asked) you should accept one of the correct answers and optionally up-vote any which have been helpful.

Comment: I can 't post the question always the red box pop out

Comment: I don't know what that means. You could almost certainly Google for how to connect many switches to an Arduino, though - and you should do research before posting the question!

Comment: Thanks for the help man , i'm really paniking now tomorrow i have ti present my project

Comment: So i need to put multiple switches with just the arduino i can get a multiplexer now

Comment: You don't need a multiplexexer. Ask another question about how to connect 8 switches to an Arduino. Maybe you'll get lucky and someone will answer - I'm going to bed. If not, think how much you'll learn about planning :-)

Answer (score 0):

A shift register is an output device. You won't be able to "Read" 7 push buttons in this way.

A shift register like that is for taking a "series" of bits on one wire and parallelizing them onto 8 wires.

It does not work in reverse. The reverse is called a multiplexer.

Comment: so using this shift register can i send data from C# to arduino code as bytes  ? I just want to compare values on my C# with values given when i press a button .

Comment: That's nonsense, jose.  See my answer re types of shift registers.

Answer (score 0):

[Shift registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register) are available in several flavors:

• [Serial-in, Serial-out (SISO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register#Serial-in_Serial-out_.28SISO.29) units like 7491 have serial input and output.

• [Serial-in, parallel-out (SIPO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register#Serial-in_parallel-out_.28SIPO.29) units like 74164 have serial input, parallel output.

• [Parallel-in, Serial-out (PISO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register#Parallel-in_Serial-out_.28PISO.29) units like 74165 or 74166 (etc. – just search for shift register in a [list of 7400 series integrated circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits) or other series) have parallel input, serial output.

Other variations: The 7494, 7495, and 7499 have serial and parallel input, parallel output.  The 7499 also has serial output.  The 7494 and 7499 can shift right or left.  (Most of the models listed earlier only shift one direction.)

Anyhow, by using an appropriate shift register, along with a bunch of resistors and diodes, it is possible to read lots of switches.  As suggested in another answer, you might want to ask about how to do that.